# Java Doubly linked list addLast() and removelast() method

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am working with doubly linked list using java and they maintain a reference to one
special node called “the sentinel node” or “nil.”. I only have one constructor to create empty list.

For my addlast class is to adds elem to the end of the list. When I test my code the console keeps saying that "Cannot read field "next" because "this.tail" is null "
Could anyone explain why and how to fix it?

For example :
at DList.addLast(DList.java:79)
at DList.main(DList.java:205)

```
import java.util.*;

public class DList implements Iterable<String> {
    
        private static class DListNode {
        public String data;
        public DListNode next;
        public DListNode previous;       
        }
        
        //Returns an iterator over the list as inner class
        private class DListIterator implements Iterator<String> {
             private DListNode pointer;

             public DListIterator() {
             if(nil.next ==nil)
             pointer = nil;
             else
             pointer = nil.next;             
             }

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return pointer.next!=null;
            }

            public String next() {
                if (!hasNext()) 
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                return pointer.next.data;
            }
        }
         
        private DListNode nil;
        private DListNode head;
        private DListNode tail;
        private int numElements;
        
         //create empty list.
        public DList() {
            nil = new DListNode();
            nil.previous = nil;
            nil.next = nil;
            nil.data = null;
            numElements = 0;
        }
        
        /*
         * //create list with element. public DList(String elem) { DListNode temp = new
         * DListNode(); this.tail = this.head = temp; numElements = 1; }
         */
        
        //adds elem to the front of the list
        public void addFirst(String elem) {
             DListNode newHead = new DListNode();
             newHead.data = elem;
             newHead.next = head;
             newHead.previous = nil;
             
             if(head==null)
                 head = newHead;
             else {
                 head.previous = newHead;
             }
             head = newHead;
             numElements++;
        }
         
        //adds elem to the end of the list
        public void addLast(String elem) {
            DListNode newTail = new DListNode();
    
            newTail.data = elem; 
            newTail.previous = tail;
              
              //If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head 
             if (head == nil) 
                 head = tail = newTail;
             else { //Change the next of last node
                 newTail = tail.next;
                 tail = newTail;
              } 
            tail = newTail;
            
            numElements++;
        }
        
        //get the first value from node
        public String getFirst() {          
            if(head==nil)
                throw new NoSuchElementException("This is empty node.");
            return head.data;
        }

        //get the last value from node
        public String getLast() {
            DListNode last = head; 
            while (last.next != null)
                last = last.next;
            
            if(last==null)
                throw new NoSuchElementException("This is empty node.");
            return last.data;
        }
        
        //get value of particular index
        public String get(int index) { 
            //looking start at index 0
            DListNode current = head;
    
            if(index<0 || index>numElements) 
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index is out of bound");
            else {
                for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
                    current = current.next;
            }
            return current.data;   
        }
         
        //changes the value at “position” index and returns the old value
        public String set(int index, String value) {
            DListNode temp = new DListNode();
            if(index<0 || index>numElements) 
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index is out of bound");
            else {
                DListNode current = head;
                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                DListNode previous = current.previous;
                previous.next = temp;
                temp.previous = previous;
                temp.next = current;
                current.previous = temp;
                numElements++;
                return temp.data;
            }
        }
        
        //Returns true if obj appears in the list and false otherwise. 
        public boolean contains(Object obj) {
            return nil.data.equals(obj);
        }
        
        //Returns the index of obj if it is in the list and -1 otherwise
        public int indexOf(Object obj) {
            if(contains(obj))
                get(numElements);
            return -1;
        }
        
        public int size() {
            return numElements;
        }
        
        public String toString() {
            String result = " ";
            DListNode temp = head;

            while(temp!=null) {
                result += temp.data + " ";
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        return result;
        }

        //removes the front element of the list and return it
        public String removeFirst() {
            if(size()==0)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            DListNode tmp = head;
            head = head.next;
            head.previous = nil;
            numElements--;
            return tmp.data;
        }
        
        //removes the last element of the list and returns it
        public String removeLast() {
            if(size()==0)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            DListNode tmp = tail;
            tail = tail.next;
            tail.next = nil;
            numElements--;
            return tmp.data;
        }
            
        //Returns an iterator over the list. 
         public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new DListIterator();
         }
        
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {  
            //create a DoublyLinkedList object
            DList dl_List = new DList();
        
            //Check the addFirst method
            dl_List.addFirst("is");
            System.out.println(dl_List);        
            dl_List.addFirst("This");
            System.out.println(dl_List);
            
            //Check the addLast method
            dl_List.addLast("Doubly");
            System.out.println(dl_List);        
            dl_List.addLast("linked");
            System.out.println(dl_List); 
            
            //check the getFirst method
            System.out.println(dl_List.getFirst());
            //check the getLast method
            System.out.println(dl_List.getLast());
            
            //test remove method
            dl_List.removeFirst();
            dl_List.removeLast();
            System.out.println(dl_List);
            
            //test get method
            System.out.println(dl_List.get(1));
            
            System.out.println(dl_List.size());
            
        }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to properly indent and format your code: tell your IDE or code editor to autoformat, and then update your post with something that others can read more easily. Also, remember that this is not a general help forum, [some work by you is expected](/help/how-to-ask): what have you already done to try and debug this? Have you run your code with debugger mode, for example? Have your tried reducing the code to the minimal example where this already goes wrong? etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is happens you aren't set tail in the constructor, so he become null.
To fix this, set tail in the constructor or add check statment to check if tail not equals to null before access tail.next.